# How to see the output console (I.E. stdout) when debugging with Xcode 5?

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, xcode5, stdout

I've searched for questions asking this, I've seen many answers about opening the console that I'm showing on the screenshot, but all I see is the console of the command line debugger lldb, not the application's output.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: I didn't know about the buffer not flushing, I though I was looking to the wrong console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is line buffered and requires a `\n` or flush to force it to print the output.

If you change your code to include the following line after every `printf` it will work the way you want.

```
printf("something I want in the console");

// Either of the next two lines should work
putchar('\n');
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: please don't mix C and C++